# Hangfire: separate background jobs for each user OR just one background job that is run frequently

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hangfire

We are using .NET 6, [Hangfire.AspNetCore 1.7.31](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hangfire.AspNetCore/1.7.31) and [Hangfire.PostgreSql 1.9.9](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hangfire.PostgreSql/1.9.9). We want to implement a way for users to subscribe to email notifications where they can choose their own notification interval. If you are familiar with Jira, it is similar to its filter subscriptions.

[image]

We see two ways of implementing this functionality:

1. Create a `RecurringJob` for each user subscription, each with its own time interval. How does this scale to 1000s of users? Does Hangfire create a separate thread for each `RecurringJob`? Can `RecurringJob`s be added at the runtime when a user subscribes to a notification?
2. Have only 1 frequent `RecurringJob` (ex. every 1 minute), which checks which users need to be notified and sends them an email.

Which option is the preferred way of doing it in Hangfire? The solution should be as efficient as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can schedule recurring jobs from code using

```
Hangfire.Core.RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<T>()
```

and, if needed, remove them first if they exist using

```
Hangfire.Core.RecurringJob.RemoveIfExists(nameof(DummyJob));
```

Instead of making recurring jobs dynamically for each user, I would rather make one job that runs every 5 minutes or so that checks if there are any user "subscriptions" (held somewhere in database), iterate through them and send notifications from that job. I'm not sure how Hangfire would behave with thousands of user created recurring jobs.

Hangfire runs jobs asycronously (using separate Threads as needed or available) .